# How to run testcafe scenario not as part of a test but as part of a node application function run

Tags: node.js, testcafe

We are using testcafe as a maing e2e testing framework, but for my pet project I'd like to use it's power to make some page actions which I can't do using API from my node web application.

Is it possible to have a function where I can open a page, make several clicks and then function returns?

I checked testcafe documentation and there is no such usecase described.

Comment: TestCafe is primarily designed for testing purposes rather than automating actions that go beyond the scope of testing. Therefore, such use cases are not described in the documentation.